# VS2019: what "Text formatting method" is?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I found in VS2019 following settings: Options > Text Editor > Advanced > Text formatting method. It can be assigned with one of three values: Automatic, Ideal and Display. I have 'Automatic'. What is it about? What happens if I change to 'Display' or 'Ideal'?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried. In case of one option, text is a little bit blurry, in case of another is not. I don't see purpose in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a WPF text rendering method corresponding to TextOptions.TextFormattingMode.

"Ideal mode text offers optimally shaped and spaced text. This translates to less reading fatigue for end users; however at small text sizes, these benefits are negated by blurry rendering. On the other hand, display mode text provides the clarity of pixel snapped text at the expense of glyph shape and placement."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/text/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements